# Ubuntu 17.04 Fresh Install: Wireless only works briefly after restarting network manager

Tags: networking, drivers, network-manager, dns

I recently installed a dual boot of Ubuntu 17.04 on my laptop. In Windows and my main desktop PC (also Windows, although I think its Ubuntu 17.04 VMWare VM connects to the web fine as well), the laptop's wireless works perfectly, but in Ubuntu the laptop's wireless speed drops out randomly, though I am always still connected to my local network. I can reliably get a few minutes of non-zero wireless access speeds by restarting network manager with

`sudo service network-manager restart`

but after those few minutes all my attempts to access websites just hang, both in browser and through the shell. Restarting network-manager has been enough to get most basic software installed but obviously isn't a good long-term solution.

I've tried a number of possible fixes based on googling people who had similar problems, e.g. changing DNSSEC to *off* in *resolved.conf*, apt update'ing, apt upgrading, apt dist-upgrade'ing, changing my IPv4 Method to Automatic (DHCP) addresses only and listing 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4 in the DNS Servers entry, looking for additional proprietary wireless drivers to install (but none appear in the Ubuntu additional drivers tab), buying a cheap PAU wireless adapter ( this one: https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B00JDVRCI0/ref=oh_aui_search_detailpage?ie=UTF8&psc=1 ) after seeing it recommended as among the more compatible with Zesty Zapus, and probably a few other 'fixes' I'm forgetting.

None of those fixes worked. My networking background is nonexistent so I'm somewhat at wit's end. I downloaded and ran the Ubuntu *Wireless & Networking* forum's diagnosis script, but I don't see anywhere to attach it here and it's rather long; I'm happy to copy/paste sections of it or run other commands to explore the problem more.

Any thoughts on what might be wrong?

*EDIT:* Per request in the comments, `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` returns:

> 01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821AE >802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8821]
>     Subsystem: XAVi Technologies Corp. RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network >Adapter [1b9a:2482]
>     Kernel driver in use: rtl8821ae
>     Kernel modules: rtl8821ae
>   02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of  `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: The RTL8821AE chipset is problematic and there is no straightforward definitive answer .

Comment: Argh, well that's not what I was hoping to hear, haha. Thanks for the information, anyway.